# Select top 10 products sold in each year

Tags: sql, oracle, db2

I have two tables :

```
Sales
columns:  (Sales_id, Date , Customer_id, Product_id, Purchase_amount):
Product 
columns:  ( Product_id, Product_Name, Brand_id,Brand_name)
```

I have to write a query to find the top 10 products sold every year. The query I have right now is :

```
WITH PH AS 
(SELECT P.Product_Name, LEFT(S.Date,4) "SYEAR", COUNT(S.Product_id) "Product Count" 
FROM Sales S LEFT JOIN Product P
ON S.Product_Id=P.Product_Id
GROUP BY P.Product_Name, LEFT(S.Date,4)

SELECT P.Product_Name, "SYEAR", "Product_Count"
FROM (SELECT P.Product_Name, "SYEAR", "Product_Count",
RANK OVER (PARTITION BY "SYEAR" ORDER BY "Product_Count" DESC) "TEMP"
)
WHERE "TEMP"<=10
```

This doesn't seem like the most optimized query. Can you please help me with that? Can there be an alternate version to obtain the required result?

> Notes

1. The main reason for the repetition of the code is to enable grouping by the year. There's no field for the year in the given table.
2. The date format is:  YYYYMMDD (example: 20200630)

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the window functions with the aggregation:

```
SELECT PY.*
FROM (SELECT P.Product_Name, LEFT(S.Date,4) AS YEAR, COUNT(*) AS CNT,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(S.Date, 4) ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS SEQNUM
      FROM Sales S LEFT JOIN
           Product P
           ON S.Product_Id = P.Product_Id
      GROUP BY P.Product_Name, LEFT(S.Date, 4)
     ) PY
WHERE SEQNUM <= 10;
```

From a performance perspective, this probably generates an execution plan very similar to your query.  It is however simpler to follow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution that you gave. Although I thought that 'PARTITION BY' cannot function with a user-defined field.

Comment: @Sharon . . . Almost any expression should work.  I am not aware of any limitations on using function calls.